# can not use pagination() for an array object in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, pagination

I am constructing an array in Laravel 5.7. I would like to paginate it, but it errors because of array feature. what shall I do?

In MyController.php:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($sameDateMatches as $key => $date) {
   array_push($result, [
   'date' => $key,
   'day_of_week' => getDayOfWeek($key),
   'matches' => $date,
    ]);
 }

 if (!empty($_GET['page'])) {
    $result = $result->paginate(10);
    $pagination = $result;
 } else {
    $result = $result;
    $pagination = null;
 }

return returnSuccessfulResponse(
   trans('api.response.successful.show'),
      [
        'Scheduled Matches' => $result,
      ],
      $pagination
 );
```

> Call to a member function paginate() on array

Comment: what's the error message? or what does the error prompt?

Comment: `Call to a member function paginate() on array`

Comment: you cant use laravel's paginate on an array, you can only use it on an eloquent model/object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problems using `make()` and `LengthAwarePaginator` as below:

```
if (!empty($_GET['page'])) {

     $per_page = !empty($_GET['per_page']) ? $_GET['per_page'] : 10;

     $page = $_GET['page'];

     $result = $result instanceof Collection ? $result : Collection::make($result);

     $result = new LengthAwarePaginator(
                    $result->forPage($page, $per_page)->values(),
                    $result->count(),
                    $per_page,
                    $page,
                    ['path' => request()->url()]
              );

     $pagination = $result;

} else {
     $pagination = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `paginate` on an instance of [QueryBuilder or on an Eloquent query](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination).

Instead, if you need to 'paginate' an array, you can use [PHP array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

```
array_chunk($result, 10, true);
```